# How to separate query result by comma

Tags: sql-server, select

I use this query

```
 SELECT cn.name from WMCCMCategories cn 
               INNER JOIN CategorySets uc ON uc.categoryId = cn.categoryID 
               INNER JOIN KeyProcesses u ON u.categorySetId = uc.setId
               INNER JOIN Companies c ON c.companyId = u.companyId
               WHERE c.companyName = 'SOME NAME'
```

and it returns one column with many rows of value.

Now I want to get one string of all that values but separated by a comma ','
So here is what I tried

```
  SELECT  STUFF((SELECT ','+   from WMCCMCategories cn 
               INNER JOIN CategorySets uc ON uc.categoryId = cn.categoryID 
               INNER JOIN KeyProcesses u ON u.categorySetId = uc.setId
               INNER JOIN Companies c ON c.companyId = u.companyId
               WHERE c.companyName = 'SOME NAME' 
              ORDER BY sortOrder
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr
 FROM WMCCMCategories cnn Group by cnn.name
```

But it gave me error at From. How to write it correctly then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  STUFF((SELECT ','+ cn.name  from WMCCMCategories cn 
               INNER JOIN CategorySets uc ON uc.categoryId = cn.categoryID 
               INNER JOIN KeyProcesses u ON u.categorySetId = uc.setId
               INNER JOIN Companies c ON c.companyId = u.companyId
               WHERE c.companyName = 'SOME NAME' 
              ORDER BY sortOrder
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr
 FROM WMCCMCategories cnn Group by cnn.name
```

Comment: It is right format, but the result return is more than 500 of same record. How could I get only one ?

Comment: try `select distinct`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the field name between your `+` and your `from`.